# unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, windows-server-2008, strongname

I have visual studio 2008 running on a Windows 2008 virtual PC.  I decided to try out the Microsoft Test Tools built into the IDE (as opposed to NUnit, which I typically use).  Using the Unit Testing wizard, VS adds a new test project to the source tree, creates a bunch of unit tests.

When I try and compile, I get this "Unable to obtain public key for StrongNameKeyPair" error.  I've checked the properties for both my project and the unit test project, and I am signing a key for each of them...

Google suggests I call
"sn.exe -m n"
"sn.exe -c"

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: How did you configure the signing of the projects ? Where does the key come from ?

Comment: I used the default key production provided by visual studio, as specified at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123.aspx

Both keys I set to be new password protected keys, but left the "delay sign only" box unchecked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/f0c75a3a-e408-4ac1-80e3-48c4837087a9) seems to describe your very problem: unit test and protected keys are not supported. The thread has suggestions and work-arounds.